# create method to generate default value with prefix and auto-increlmentation directly in entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, constructor, repository

In my **Symfony** project I have this entity named `Order.php`:

```
<?php

namespace myApp\EntityBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Datetime;


/**
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="`order`")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="myApp\EntityBundle\Repository\OrderRepository")
 *
 */
class Order
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="order_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * Command name ref for right accounting
     *
     * @var string
     *
     * @Assert\Type(
     *     type="string",
     *     message="The value {{ value }} is not a valid {{ type }}."
     * )
     * @Assert\NotNull()
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @ORM\Column(name="order_name", type="string", length=255, nullable=true, unique=true)
     */
    protected $orderName;

    // etc other associations, object and getters setters...

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->generateOrderName();
    }

    /**
     * generate order_name with base ref
     *
     * @return Order
     */
    public function generateOrderName()
    {
        // trying to make the good practice for generated orderName value
        //$now = new Datetime();
        //$year = $now->format("Y");
        //$month = $now->format("m");
        //$orderNameCommon = $year."_".$month."_";

        $this->setOrderName();
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set orderName
     *
     * @param string $orderName
     *
     * @return Order
     */
    public function setOrderName($orderName)
    {
        $this->orderName = $orderName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get orderName
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getOrderName()
    {
        return $this->orderName;
    }
}
```

The purpose is to generate an orderName like this: '2016_09_00001' which means that I registered order by date Year_Month_orderNumber.

I have to take care that the orderName have to be unique, and for example if I have already an order named '2016_09_00001', I have to register the orderName like this '2016_09_00002'. Like an auto-incrementation for example.

As you can see, I have made this code directly in entity class Order:

```
/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    // call the order name generation function
    $this->generateOrderName();
}

/**
 * generate order_name with base ref
 *
 * @return Order
 */
public function generateOrderName()
{
    $now = new Datetime();
    $year = $now->format("Y");
    $month = $now->format("m");
    $prefix = $year."_".$month."_";

    // That I had planned:
    // to create a prefix with Datetime argument, year and month
    // Then check all order in database with this prefix
    // Finally count the results and add +1 on the final value

    $this->setOrderName();
    return $this;
}
```

As you can see, I have called the `generateOrderName()` function in the **constructor**, and then I would like to make this process:

> That I had planned:
>
> 1. to create a prefix with Datetime argument, year and month
> 2. Then check all order in database with this prefix
> 3. Finally count the results and add +1 on the final value

What is the best way to make this properly in the entity directly? I think it's not a good thing to have a repository dql query call in the entity class itself.

I have create this one for example:

```
public function searchOrderName($prefix)
{
    return
        $this->getEntityManager()
             ->createQuery(
              "SELECT o.orderName FROM EntityBundle:Order o
               WHERE o.orderName
               LIKE :prefix
               ORDER BY o.id ASC"
            )
             ->setParameter("prefix", $prefix.'%')
             ->getResult();
}
```

How can I proceed to create the `generateOrderName()` function in the entity to make the generated process I would like directly in entity class ?

Answer (score 3):

You will need a service for it. You cannot access DB from your Entity. So make OrderFactory, inject there OrderRepository and you will easily reach your goal